# How do I restore compiz advanced zoom?

Tags: compiz, zooming

I lost compiz zoom due to some incompatibility that I am not sure about. I read about a fix before, but I forgot what it is. When I try to zoom with the super key and mouse it just vibrates the cursor.

After further testing to find the problem, I know it has to be something that is trying to put the pointer to the centre of the screen. Hopefully someone will be able to track down the cause, because so far I cannot.

EDIT - I've tried all kinds of options, including resetting all the settings on the plugin, still no change. I can't zoom, even if I change the keys. If it helps, restraining the mouse to the zoom area makes it jump to one side of the screen.

Could it be that I have dual outputs that is causing the problem?

Comment: Your mouse vibrates?

Comment: so said so done =D

Comment: the cursor I should say

Comment: Try to reset it to default settings(gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz).Restart your ubuntu system and try again.

Comment: I'm quite sure there was an application or plugin blocking it :(.. I just wish someone knew which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a bug when using dual monitors. As far as I know the only current fix is to unplug a monitor. You may be able to get it working by editing the General options in ccsm to not autodetect outputs and instead manually specify your monitors' sizes and positions.

Comment: I had fixed the problem before (forgot how I did it), but this is a method that works, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're also using the desktop cube, make sure you have "multiple cubes" selected in the desktop cubes "Multi Output Mode" list.

Comment: I'm using Unity, and I since found out what the problem is, it is Nvidia's TwinView.